# Guidance completing a proof

Tags: coq, proof, theorem-proving

I'd appreciate some guidance completing this proof. I'm stuck in the last `admit` (I have completed the other ones without problems, but I omit the real proof).

I have added comments following my reasoning, because I think it explains better than me trying to describe it in a paragraph.

This is the the definition of the functions in use:

```
In = 
fix In (A : Type) (x : A) (l : list A) {struct l} : Prop := match l with
                                                            | [ ] => False
                                                            | x' :: l' => x' = x \/ In A x l'
                                                            end
     : forall A : Type, A -> list A -> Prop

Argument A is implicit and maximally inserted
Argument scopes are [type_scope _ _]
```

---

```
map = 
fix map (X Y : Type) (f : X -> Y) (l : list X) {struct l} : list Y := match l with
                                                                      | [ ] => [ ]
                                                                      | h :: t => f h :: map X Y f t
                                                                      end
     : forall X Y : Type, (X -> Y) -> list X -> list Y

Arguments X, Y are implicit and maximally inserted
Argument scopes are [type_scope type_scope function_scope _]
```

---

And here it is the lemma:

```
Lemma foo :
  forall (A B : Type) (f : A -> B) (l : list A) (y : B),
    In y (map f l) <->
    exists x, f x = y /\ In x l.
Proof.
  intros A B f l y. split.
  - admit.
  - induction l as [|x0 l' HIl'].
    * admit.
    * (*
      HIl': (exists x : A, f x = y /\ In x l') -> In y (map f l')
      Goal: (exists x : A, f x = y /\ In x (x0 :: l')) -> In y (map f (x0 :: l'))
      *)
      intros H. simpl.
      (*
      Goal: f x0 = y \/ In y (map f l')
      *)
      right.
      (*
      Taking the right side, because if `f x0 = y`, then the induction
      hypothesis would tell us nothing.
      *)
      apply HIl'.
      (*
      Goal: exists x : A, f x = y /\ In x l'
      *)
      destruct H as [x1 H']. exists x1.
      (*
      This `x1` should be the element that is in both `l'` and `x0 ::
      l'`, because we discarded the case when `f x0 = y`.

      Goal: f x1 = y /\ In x1 l'
      *)
      destruct H' as [H'l H'r]. split.
      + (* Goal: fx1 = y *) apply H'l .
      + (* Goal: In x1 l' *)
        (*
           `x1` must be in `l'`, because we know it is in x0 :: l` by H'r:
           H'r: In x1 (x0 :: l')
           and we discarded the case where `f x0 = y`.
        *)
        destruct H'r as [H'rl | H'rr].
        { (* Stuck!!! *) admit. }
        { apply H'rr. } Abort.
```

Comment: `Taking the right side` — that is really strange. Suppose you're proving induction step for a singleton list. Then it's actually possible that you need the left side because `l'` is empty and the match you're looking for is the first and only element of the list. So you need to understand whether it's the case somehow.

Comment: I wasn't able to compile your code in CoqIDE 8.8.0 right away. Would you mind providing [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It looks like only some syntax modifications (e.g. commenting out comments) are required, as you have most definitions here already.

Comment: Sorry @yeputons, I thought it was a MCVE (I supposed `In` an `map` were part of the standard distrubution besides being redefined in the book I'm studying). But now I completed the proof thanks to your comment and other anwers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `right.` tactic is too early. At this point `H` tells us `x` is in `(x0 :: l)`, but what if that is because `x = x0`? Then there is no way to prove the right alternative, but the left one is true in that case. Hence you must deconstruct `H` before choosing the `left` or `right` side.

Answer (score 3):

```
Lemma foo :
  forall (A B : Type) (f : A -> B) (l : list A) (y : B),
    In y (map f l) <->
    exists x, f x = y /\ In x l.
Proof.
  - admit.
  - induction l as [|x0 l' HIl'].
    * admit.
    * (*
      -- HIl': (exists x : A, f x = y /\ In x l') -> In y (map f l')
      -- Goal: (exists x : A, f x = y /\ In x (x0 :: l')) -> In y (map f (x0 :: l'))
      *)
      intros H. simpl.
      (*
      -- Goal: f x0 = y \/ In y (map f l')

      you might need to destruct H first.
       *)
      destruct H.
      destruct H.
      (* right. *)
      (*
      -- Taking the right side, because if `f x0 = y`, then the induction
      -- hypothesis would tell us nothing.
      acatually, consider x = x0, we can subst and just apply H here.
      we will destruct on H0 to analysis case x = x0 || In x l'.
       *)
      destruct H0. {
        left.
        rewrite H0.
        assumption.
      }
      (* in this case we select rhs. *)
      {
        right.
        apply HIl'.
        exists x.
        split. {
          assumption.
        }
        {
          assumption.
        }
      }
Admitted.
```

Sorry that I was at work, I thought I would edit this in a minute.

You will notice that the hypothesis of `In x l` should be destructed then analyzed separately. As you do induction on l, it replaces to `In x (x0 :: l)`, the conjunctive should hold either for `x = x0` or `In x l`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @HexadecimalHyuga. It seems a complete answer. I'll look at it closer later, but before I prefer to wait whether someone gives me a clue (and not the answer itself) that helps me to find the answer myself :)

Answer (score 3):

```
Lemma foo :
  forall (A B : Type) (f : A -> B) (l : list A) (y : B),
    In y (map f l) <->
    exists x, f x = y /\ In x l.
Proof.
  induction l; split; intros.
  - now inversion H.
  - now firstorder.
  - inversion H.
    + now exists a; firstorder.
    + apply IHl in H0.
      destruct H0 as [x Hx].
      now exists x; firstorder.
  - destruct H as [x [Hx [Hi | Hi]]].
    + now left; subst.
    + right.
      apply IHl.
      exists x.
      firstorder.
Qed.
```

Comment: Incidentally, `Proof. induction l; firstorder congruence. Qed.` also solves the goal. I often find this `firstorder congruence` combination quite powerful. The proof of this lemma (called `in_map_iff`) in the standard library is as follows: `induction l; firstorder (subst; auto).`